# Why are is my 7 speed chain drive slipping? in the lower gears

Tags: drivetrain-slipping

I've  noticed when I ride in 1st or 2nd gear that the chain drive slips then engages then slips again.Especially when going up ridiculously low grade inclines, such as ramps at crosswalks. 
What is causing this issue and how do I repair it?! This is on a 7 speed adult tricycle.

Comment: I would guess that the derailer is mis-adjusted.  Or perhaps your cogs & chain are worn.  Or perhaps your chain is too long for the small front sprocket.

Comment: This is a brand new bicycle, purchased from overseas. I had to put the trike together right out of the box, nothing was pre-assembled. The indexing seems to be ok. Although, having never done indexing before,I might not have it exactly right. The assembly instructions were shady at best, being this trike came from China. Only one Chain-ring in front.

Comment: Probably worth paying a local bike shop to tune it up.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines, although that is usually pretty expensive.

Comment: Wouldn't be terribly expensive here -- I'm guessing 10-20 bucks.

Comment: Check for tight links in the chain. If you find any, you will have to loosen them slightly with a chain tool.